# Can't Get Shell Scripts to Run

Tags: bash, terminal, homebrew, macos-mojave

I recently reinstalled Mojave on my Macbook Pro.  Before the install, I had several bash scripts written, all of which were executable by double-clicking on them.  They are all .command extensions. For each file, I ran chmod +x to make it executable.  The shebang in each of the scripts is: `#! /usr/bin/env bash`

After the install, I cannot get the scripts to run by double-clicking.  If I access the scripts through terminal, they run fine.  But if I double-click, it opens a terminal window with the title of the script, but nothing happens, the script never executes.

I installed bash through homebrew, then entered `/usr/local/bin/bash` into `/etc/shells`.  In terminal, if I enter `which bash` it returns `/usr/local/bin/bash`.  If I enter `echo $SHELL` it returns `/bin/bash`.

I want my system to be running the bash 5 that homebrew installed.  I thought I had my terminal configured correctly, but I can't figure this out.  Any help would be extremely appreciated.

I attached a screenshot of the terminal output too in case it would be helpful.  I wrote a script for an example titled "hello.command":

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Hello'
```

This is what shows up if I double click it:

[image]

Comment: Did you set it as your default shell with `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`?

Comment: Yep, actually when I enter that it asks for my password then returns this    "chsh: /usr/local/bin/bash: non-standard shell"  should that not be happening?

Comment: Did you try it before you edited `/etc/shells`? That's what you'd see if the shell you're trying to set as the default isn't in there.

Comment: Ahh Ben thank you!!! To be honest I very well could have and not even realized it.  I just reset the /etc/shells to default, set the shell to /bin/bash, uninstalled homebrew's bash, reinstalled it, added it to the /etc/shells file, then switched it and everything is working perfectly.  Thank you for helping my stupid mistake

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/shells`, add an entry on a newline:

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Note that to add this entry to `/etc/shells`, you need root privileges.

Comment: They mention that they did that in the question.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry i missed that, could you try to go to `terminal`, then `preferences`, and instead of `default login shell` change it to `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: it's no problem, I really appreciate the help with this, I'm not overly confident in my abilities with Mac.  I actually had a screenshot of that too, but it would only let me upload one file.  Under "shells opens with" it was already set to "complete path" then /usr/local/bin/bash

Comment: @Anthony, could you show me the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Just got it working @Benjamin W. had me realize I did some things out of order.  Thank you both for your help